# Generar apk cordova

Tags: android, cordova, apk

**Cuando genero el apk con cordova**

Agrego la paltaforma de android

```
cordova platform add android
```

luego construyo la aplicación

```
cordova build android
```

Se genera la aplicación.

Pero como se que api esta tomando del sdk(si instale varios en mi sdk).
¿?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeramente necesitas conocer las siguientes definiciones:

> [**minSdkVersion**](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html#min) : indica desde que API tu aplicación es
>   soportada.
>
> [**maxSdkVersion**](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html#max) : indica hasta que versión de API tu aplicación
>   es soportada.
>
> [**targetSdkVersion**](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html#target) indica con que API tu aplicación es
>   compilada, Valor entero que designa el nivel de API al cual se dirige
>   la aplicación. Si no se configura, el valor predeterminado es igual al
>   valor asignado a la minSdkVersion.

Ahora para saber la versión cuando se genera el proyecto:

```
$ cordova platform add android
$ cordova build android
```

revisa dentro del archivo

```
platforms/android/AndroidManifest.xml
```

o para [Cordova Android 7.0.0](http://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2017/12/04/cordova-android-7.0.0.html) dentro de:

```
app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml.
```

ahí encontrarás las propiedades antes mencionadas.

---

Estos valores los puedes sobreescribir dentro del archivo `config.xml` puedes definir la versión definir el minimo SDK a usar y el target con el cual se creara tu aplicación.

```
<platform name="android">
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="16" />
    <preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="26" />
</platform>
```

Answer (score 1):

Esto lo puedes verificar en el archivo:

```
platforms/android/AndroidManifest.xml
```

El cual es generado al momento de ejecutar el comando. La versión la encuentras específicamente en las lineas:

```
android:minSdkVersion="10" android:targetSdkVersion="19"
```

Si necesitas modificar la versión de android puedes ejecutar el comando cordova platform add android especificando la x versión de la siguiente manera:

```
cordova platform add android@x.x.x
```

Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Lo puedes encontrar en el archivo **AndroidManifest.xml**, en mi caso lo tengo ubicado en la ruta "platforms/android/AndroidManifest.xml", buscas lo siguiente:

```
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16" android:targetSdkVersion="25" />
```

O puedes buscar en tu archivo **config.xml**

```
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="16" />
```

Espero te sirva!